# Laravel 5.3 Session not closing

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I closed the browser without logging off. I saw the closure of the session when I open the browser again.The session when the browser closes must also shut down.
can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to review config/session.php

check this
http://www.snippetcase.com/snippet/26/Remove+session+after+closing+the+browser+in+laravel

Answer (score 0):

Session is used to prevent to loose data when you close the browser so I don't think there is a "correct" way to do that.

You can flush your session data with

```
$request->session()->flush();
```

Otherwise you can try to delete the Laravel Cookie when you .unload() the window.

Comment: no it's not. No problem when I do normal logout. When I close the browser session does not close

Comment: Yes it is. You are comparing the logout (an action that involves a server side action) with the closing of a windows (that is a client side action)

Answer (score 0):

Laravel sessions is a server side, but browser close is a client side event. You can send additional request on browser close or just delete cookies. It will looks like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
    var cookies = document.cookie.split(";");

    for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = cookies[i];
        var eqPos = cookie.indexOf("=");
        var name = eqPos > -1 ? cookie.substr(0, eqPos) : cookie;
        document.cookie = name + "=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT";
    }
}
```

Comment: a temporary solution. thanks anyway.. When I want to use cookies could cause problems.